# Rails 4 ActiveRecord undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I’m trying to retrieve individual attributes from a record after retrieving it from the database. I get an error indicating an undefined method.

I retrieve the table here:

```
t = Table.where('@@fil = ? ', r.referenced_object_ID)
```

I know I’m getting a record because I can list all the attributes in the record using:

```
t.to_json
```

and get this result:

```
[{"@@fil":"1026.0","objtyp":"FIL","objatr":"CPT","fil":"Account”,…
```

However, when I try to use:

```
t.fil
```

I get

```
undefined method ‘fil’…
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To directly get single record if fil is unique**

```
t = Table.find_by_fil(r.referenced_object_ID)
```

**If fil is not unique then use your approach then use**

```
 t.first.fill #to get first record
```

**Or if you need all record use loop**

```
t..each do |tbl|
 tbl.fil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

'where' clause always returns us an array. So in your case you can access it as

```
t.first.fil
```